# How to free memory allocated to Main, running out of memory

Tags: ubuntu, out-of-memory

I'm having trouble on my Ubuntu 18.04 system where all of my memory is running out. Stopping all of the programs running does not seem to release all the memory (it only made 42Mb available).

After stopping my major processes I'm left with:

```
free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       24582460    24202708      199016       53188      180736       42996
Swap:       8388604     4638556     3750048
```

When I use top to view the top users of memory I get:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1525 root      39  19 23.656g 0.020t   2552 S   2.3 86.3   1971:07 Main
```

Is there any way to free up memory allocated to `Main` or to see how that memory is being used?

I will be troubleshooting why this is happening soon. I suspect it is being caused by my Shiny Server Pro instance, although it may also be happening because of code run in my Rstudio Server Pro instance. But at this point I'm hoping to find a way to free up the memory without rebooting the server every time this happens while I'm trying to root cause it.

Comment: think best approach would be first to identify what software does the process belong to and tweak the software. Worst case, add more RAM. You could use `lsof` command to identify files opened by the process, which may help identifying what program is using it. Also, simple `ps auxfw` may give you a process tree and you might see what the process belongs to.

Comment: Ah, both of those are commands I wasn't familiar with before. I'll have to hunt through them.

Comment: try also `pstree` - a command that shows the running processes as a tree. Determine what the process belongs to and tweak if appropriate.

Comment: This is very helpful. I also hadn't realized I could use the `c` button to show more details on the `top` display.